Is it possible to force an install4j launcher exe to use the JRE search sequence instead of the bundled JRE?
We would like to call the launcher exe from the application itself, in order to relaunch it with an updated JRE located somewhere in the data directory.
We cannot update/replace:

<program files>/myapp/jre (the application already loaded this VM)
<program files>/myapp/.install4j/pref_jre.cfg (protected / needs elevated permissions)

We thought we could maybe add a custom entry to the jre search sequence and then call the launcher exe with this custom environment variable set:

Actually it would be great if the generated launchers had options similar to the installer options, e.g. INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME_OVERRIDE: https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/installers/options.html
Or maybe an option like -manual named -forceJreSearch or similar.

Update: Doesn't work because compiler variables have to be provided at compile time, and we need something at launch time.

Idea 1: (Ab)use Java min/max version to force JRE search sequence by calling the launcher with env.JRE_VERSION set to something very specific, which is provided by env.JAVA_HOME (or env.CUSTOM_VARIABLE).


Update: Both attempts didn't work.

Idea 2: Override Java version at the launcher level to force JRE search sequence (and skip bundled jre).
Attempt with plain environment variable syntax as seen in the java invocation VM parameters field:

Attempt to to see if ${launcher:env.VAR} works the same as ${compiler:env.VAR}.

